# Access to custom objects in unordered_set

Tags: c++, stl

Please help to figure out the logic of using unordered_set with custom structures.
Consider I have following class

```
struct MyClass {
int id;
// other members
};
```

used with shared_ptr

```
using CPtr = std::shared_ptr<MyClass>;
```

Because of fast access by key I supposed to use an unordered_set with a custom hash and the MyClass::id member as a key):

```
template <class T> struct CHash;
template<> struct CHash<CPtr>
{
  std::size_t operator() (const CPtr& c) const
  {
    return std::hash<decltype(c->id)> {} (c->id);
  }
};
using std::unordered_set<CPtr, CHash>;
```

Right now, unordered_set still seems to be an appropriate container. However standard find() functions for sets are assumed to be const to ensure keys won't be changed. I intend to change objects guaranteeing keeping keys unchanged. So, the questions are:

1) How to realize easy accessing to element of set by int key reserving possibility to change element, something like

```
auto element = my_set.find(5);
element->b = 3.3;
```

It is possible to add converting constructor and use something like

```
auto element = my_set.find(MyClass (5));
```

But it doesn't solve the problem with constness and what if the class is huge.

2) Am I actually going wrong way? Should I use another container? For example unordered_map, that will store one more int key for each entry consuming more memory.

Comment: If you worry about the overhead of one int per object, then I'd think about whether you really want to use a unordered_set/map and shared_ptr at all.

Comment: Well, I can't  predict heaviness of my task precisely. Single map with 100 elements will hold 100 additional ints. If I have 1000*1000 maps of about 100 elements each, there will be 1000*1000*100 additional ints.

Comment: @qlog: A unordered set will have a per element overhead anyways (at least a single pointer - maybe more). So does a `shared_ptr`. So again. If you worry about the per-element overhead so much, then you are using the wrong datastructures anyway.

Comment: Btw.: If you don't use a custom allocator, the per element overhead of a `unordered_set/map` will probably be much bigger, because each entry is allocated dynamically, wich entails some overhead on it's own.

Comment: Ok, I will think about raplacing shared_ptr with ordinary pointer. I assumed that container's overhead is the payment for its accomodations, shared_ptr overhead is payment for safety when using pointers. And what advantages I gained with maps except of I don't know how to solve the problem without maps)

Comment: The advantage is that it provides the interface you want (lookup by key + modifiable value). If you don't need shared ownership, I woul use `unique_ptr` instead of `shared_ptr` which has no overhead but is still safe (for some definitions of safe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer doesn't project its constness to the object it points to. Meaning, if you have a constant reference to a `std::shared_ptr` (as in a set) you can still modify the object via this pointer. Whether or not that is something you should do a is a different question and it doesn't solve your lookup problem.

OF course, if you want to lookup a value by a key, then this is what `std::unordered_map` was designed for so I'd have a closer look there. The main problem I see with this approach is not so much the memory overhead (`unordered_set` and `unordered_map` as well as `shared_ptr` have noticeable memory overhead anyway), but that you have to maintain redundant information (`id` in the object and `id` as a key).

If you have not many insertions and you don't absolutely need the (on average) constant lookup time and memory overhead is really important to you, you could consider a third solution (besides using a third-party or self written data structure of courses): namely to write a thin wrapper around a sorted `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>` or - if appropriate - even better `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>>` that uses `std::upper_bound` for lookups.

Comment: I want to clarify your answer, just in case: there is no an easy way to add custom access for a set. Alternatives are either to use another container such as map or to create my own container. Am I right?

Comment: @qloq: As far as I know: Yes

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going a wrong way using unordered_set,because unordered_set's definition is very clear that:

> Keys are immutable, therefore, the elements in an unordered_set cannot be modified once in the container - they can be inserted and removed, though.

You can see its definition in site:

> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_set/unordered_set/.

And hope it is helpful for you.Thanks.

Comment: you don't need to "thank" who created the question :)

Comment: @Emiliano:Thank you for your friendly reminder. I just registered an account not long ago and not very clearly to the site's rule.